# Input a null value with cin or getline()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input, cin, getline

I'm trying to make a program that outputs random numbers between 1 and 21 with a loop. To exit the loop, you've to digit 'c' or 'C' and I want to make it continue the loop by pressing only ENTER, but the cin function doesn't accept a null input. Could you help me?

The code is like this:

```
char input[100];
int number;
do{
   //reset the variable
   input[]=null;
   cin>>input;
   if(input){
      number=rand()%21+1;
   }
   cout>>number;
} while (input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::string` instead of a char array, and then use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get exactly one line.

```
std::string input;
while (std::getline(std::cin, input) && input != "c" && input != "C") {
    std::cout << (rand() % 21 + 1) << '\n';
}
```

---

As an aside, it looks like you're using `using namespace std;`. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was trying to do that in another program, but it doesn't work. Could you explain me why?
`while(std::getline(std::cin, input) && input != "c" && input != "C") {
        myfile << input << "\n";
    };`
P.S: _myfile_ is declared as `std::fstream myfile;`

Comment: @DVD_DAVIDE Presumably you need to change `std::cin` to `myfile` but I can't say for sure without a better explanation of the problem than "doesn't work" and it would also help to see the complete source code.